# Exclude certain token pattern from production rule in JavaCC

Tags: javacc

Assume that we have the production rule **Expression** that can choose between **LogicExpression**, **MathExpression**, **StringExpression**, and **ListExpression**.

```
void Expression() #void: {}
{
    LOOKAHEAD(3) LogicExpression() | LOOKAHEAD(3) MathExpression() | 
    LOOKAHEAD(2) StringExpression() | ListExpression()
}
```

All four of these production rules may evaluate to the token IDENTIFIER, so the expression IDENTIFIER + 1 will encounter a ParseException because the IDENTIFIER resolves to a **LogicExpression** instead of the whole thing resolving to a **MathExpression**. Is there a way to exclude a lone IDENTIFIER from being part of a production rule?

Comment: Don't try to do type checking with a grammar. Just recognise expressions, and check that the operand types make sense for each operator during post-parse semantic analysis.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There isn't a straightforward way to match everything that matches a pattern X except those that match a pattern Y.

But that's not your problem.  Your problem seems to be that you want to parse expressions.  There is a straight-forward way to do that.

```
void Expression() #void: {}
{
    LOOKAHEAD(LogicExpression())
    LogicExpression()
|
    LOOKAHEAD(MathExpression())
    MathExpression()
| 
    LOOKAHEAD(StringExpression())
    StringExpression()
|
    ListExpression()
}
```

For inputs that can be matched more by more than one of the choices, the first choice that works will by chosen.